# laravel check if user has a created an profile

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

For example:

when a user logged or registered in for the first time and didnt make a profile yet is there anyway u can check where ever he made a profile so u can send him an alert to make one incase he didnt make a profile yet.

Does laravel have Helper functions for that or u need to do someting like this?

```
 if(\Auth::check())

    {

        $user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $profile = Profile::where('id', $profile->id)->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();
        if($profile->count() > 0 ) {

            return false;

        } else {

            return true;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a `Profile`table to hold information from the `User` without merging them together, you will want to:

1. Run on the project root folder:

   php artisan make:migration:schema create_profiles_table --schema="user_id:integer:foreign, title:string"
2. Create the relationship:

**User Model**

```
public function profiles()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

**Profile Model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

3. Check if a User have a profile:

**In your controller**

```
if (is_null(Auth::user()->profiles)) {
    //your logic here
}
```